# comparing two files diff awk else

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

Could you please quickly help me with this? I have two files with 1 columns in each file. I need to compare fileA to fileB and find out which items in FileA are already in FILEB and print them out to another file.So basically like to find out which name they have in common.

so I have something like this

```
FILEA

MATT.1
HANNA.1
OTTOO.2
MARK.2
SAM.3

FILEB

SAM.3
MATT.1
JEFF.6
ALI.8
```

The result file should be

```
SAM.3
MATT.1
```

I was thinking of writing a shell script cat one file and do a line by line comparison, but there must a better and easier way to do this using one of many commands. Can you help?

Regards

Comment: diff -y filea fileb | sort | grep -v \< | grep -v \>   << Horrible way of doing things but this works , I'm sure tehre is an easier way

Answer (score 3):

This is a job for [`comm`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/comm.1.html). The input files need to be sorted though

```
comm -12 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

will give you the common lines.

An awk answer:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {f[$0]=1; next} $0 in f' fileb filea
```

Put the smaller file as the first argument to limit the amount of memory required.

Answer (score 2):

This looks returns lines from filea that match any line in fileb:

```
$ grep -Ff fileb filea
MATT.1
SAM.3
```

`-F` tells grep to look for fixed patterns, not regular expressions.

`-f` tells grep to get the list of patterns from a file which, in this case, is `fileb`.

#### More options

We can make the matches more restrictive with these options:

`-w` would tell grep to match only whole words.

`-x` would tell grep to match only whole lines.

Comment: but if there were more than one column

Comment: if there were first name and last name ?

Comment: `grep -f a1 b1` means that the lines in `a1` are treated as regular expressions.  If you are new to regular expressions, that can lead to unpleasant surprises.  _"if there were more than one column"_  That depends.

Comment: You need some other arg to stop "john" from matching "johnson".

Comment: @EdMorton I added info on `-w` and `-x` to the answer.  As for whether or not such options are "needed," I think the OP should refine his goals to make that clear.